# go to definition gedit plugin

Tags: ctags, gedit

Is there a "go to definition" plugin in gedit?

Answer (score 1):

if i [ask google](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&expIds=17259,18167,26473,27022,27466,27740,27744&xhr=t&q=gedit+%22go+to+definition%22+plugin&cp=24&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=38fb184d66b401b2), this is the [first hit](http://osdir.com/ml/gedit-list/2009-08/msg00009.html):

> Hello Friends,
>
> I have developed a plug-in  coded in a
>   python for the auto-completion and go
>   to definition features.
>
> go to definition --- this feature
>   provide the user to jum to to the
>   definition of variable. In the right
>   click menu "Go to definition" option
>   is provided to the user.
>
> [...]

Comment: Ok, I have seen that... but there's no link to download

Comment: sorry, i havn't seen that. but if you take a look at this: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2009-August/msg00009.html there's the mail-address of that guy...